# How to save uploaded file in different name with actual physical path in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a file upload in my code. I want to save that file in different name (i.e patient id + timestamp) but i could not save the uploaded file in actual physical location. its shows format is not correct.

here location and deptcode taken from session.and mainpath is taken from variable defined in web.config. thats base path. from that base path i am creating sub folders is its not there and then have to save uploaded file in different name. values are all correct.even i could create subfolders if its not there ,but only problem is saveas line. i cannot save uploaded file.
here if i use SaveAs(Server.MapPath(..)) it shows u should use virtual path.
if i use only saveas(filelocation) then it shows format is wrong..please help me..

Comment: can you please specify value of filelocationpat

Comment: @Parv Sharma its D:\UploadedAttachment\AT\MRD\AT0520130008_15/05/2013 10:14:30.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();` this return some thing like this `5/15/2013 10:14:18 AM`. A window folder And File Can not Contain  following characters:
`\ / : * ? " < > |` and your `DateTime.Now`returing one of this this character that is `: and /` that why its giving you this error.Remove `:` by `DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(':','-').Replace('/','-');` i think it will work.

Comment: i tried that, but got error like this:
Could not find a part of the path 'D:\UploadedAttachment\AT\MRD\AT0520130008_15\05\2013 10-27-56.jpg'.

Comment: should i replace date '\' also?? hoe to do that?

Comment: yeah you haver to replace it too i update my answer because these two character are invalid in file name...

Comment: cant write 2 replace . showing syntax error. also \ is considered as new line i guess..

Comment: Hey thanks alot. i used DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy-hh-mm-ss"). worked. :-)

Comment: hello please help for this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579410/how-to-open-image-or-pdf-file-in-a-new-window

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the ":" from your DateTime.Now.ToString(). You can use the ToString() method with string format to change it. Example:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy-hh-mm-ss")
```

This should solve the problem

Comment: please help for this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579410/how-to-open-image-or-pdf-file-in-a-new-window

Answer (score 0):

you should change 
`string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();` to

```
string timestamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
```

or to

```
string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss");
```

this will append a long number converted to string and therefore it will generate a valid name and also you will have a valid timestamp

Comment: Hey thanks alot. i used DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy-hh-mm-ss"). worked. :-)

Comment: please help for this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579410/how-to-open-image-or-pdf-file-in-a-new-window

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    FbDataAdapter daa = new FbDataAdapter();///////////////////time :1.00 to 9.00
    string da = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    string date = da.Substring(0, 2);
    string date1 = da.Substring(3, 4 - 2);
    string date2 = da.Substring(6, 9 - 5);
    string daietime = "D" + date + "M" + date1 + "Y" + date2;

    int f = da.IndexOf(":");
    int l = da.Length;
    string main = da.Substring(11, f - 11);
    string refer = da.Substring(13, f - 10);
    string refer1 = da.Substring(16, f - 10);
    string refer2 = da.Substring(19, f - 10);
    string time = "H" + main + "M" + refer + "S" + refer1 + "S" + refer2;
    // uploadedfilename means FileUpload Control 
    uploadedfilename.SaveAs(@Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "images\\"+ daietime + time + Path.GetExtension(uploadedfilename.FileName));

}
catch
{
    string da = DateTime.Now.ToString();//////////////////////// Time :10.00 to 12.00
    string date = da.Substring(0, 2);
    string date1 = da.Substring(3, 4 - 2);
    string date2 = da.Substring(6, 9 - 5);
    string daietime = "D" + date + "M" + date1 + "Y" + date2;

    int f = da.IndexOf(":");
    int l = da.Length;
    string main = da.Substring(11, f - 11);
    string refer = da.Substring(14, f - 11);
    string refer1 = da.Substring(17, f - 11);
    string refer2="";
    string time="";
    try
    {
        refer2 = da.Substring(20, f - 11);
        time = "H" + main + "M" + refer + "S" + refer1 + "S" + refer2;
    }
    catch
    {
        refer2 = "H" + main + "M" + refer + "S" + refer1;
        time = "H" + main + "M" + refer + "S" + refer1 + "S" + refer2;
    }
   uploadedfilename.SaveAs(@Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "images\\"+ daietime + time + Path.GetExtension(uploadedfilename.FileName));
}
```

Comment: hey i got it..i just used DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy-hh-mm-ss"). worked. :-)..your code is bit lengthy. i prefer to keep it simple..dont mind ..thanks :-)

Comment: please help for this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579410/how-to-open-image-or-pdf-file-in-a-new-window