# How to open image or pdf file in a new window?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have a gridview it contains file names and path of files (image and pdf format files) in that i used template field under that i put 1 image buttoon. on clicking of that image button i.e view button i want to open selected file in a new window.

here is my code :

```
protected void GVViewFile_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = GVViewFile.SelectedIndex;
    string path = GVViewFile.Rows[id].Cells[2].Text.ToString();

    Response.Redirect("D:\UploadedAttachment\AT\MRD\AT0520130008_15-05-13-03-57-12.pdf");

    Response.Write("<script>");
   Response.Write("window.open('" + path + "','_blank', ' fullscreen=yes')");
   //Response.Write("window.open(" + path + ",'_blank')");
   Response.Write("</script>");

}
```

but i could not open in new window. my path returns same value as inside response.write(). whe i use just `response.write("images/UserDetails.pdf");` as example it will show pdf page..but full path is not taking. also it shows `'\'` is wrong in `response.write();` so how to use actual full path to display image or pdf in new window..please help me.even that window.open is giving error.i cannot write full path in window.open since i am getting selected path from gridview.help please....

my gridview code :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GVViewFile" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="DSforgridview" onselectedindexchanged="GVViewFile_SelectedIndexChanged"
        HeaderStyle-BackColor="#CC6600" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" 
    PagerStyle-BackColor="#CC6600" PagerStyle-ForeColor="White" CellPadding="3" 
    CellSpacing="3" PagerStyle-Width="4" PagerStyle-Height="4" 
    BorderColor="#FF6600" BorderStyle="Solid">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnView" runat="server" 
                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select"
                ImageUrl="~/Images/view.gif" ToolTip="View File" />
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="FileType" HeaderText="FileType" 
                SortExpression="FileType" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FileLocationPath" HeaderText="FileLocationPath" 
                SortExpression="FileLocationPath" />
        </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CC6600" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>No Records Found.</EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: @cherhan i pasted, but prob is not in gridview , prob is i cannot open the path (i.e like D:\UploadedAttachment\AT\MRD\AT0520130008_15-05-13-03-57-12.pdf) in new window..

Comment: "~/UploadedAttachment\AT\MRD\AT0520130008_15-05-13-03-57-12.pdf" try like this...

Comment: what browser you are using ?

Comment: @AmitSingh '\' shows synatx error

Comment: no not working got error like this :cannot find /PMS-V-10-5/UploadedAttachment/AT/MRD/AT0520130008_15-05-13-03-57-12.pdf
PMS-V-10-5 is my project folder, scope is limited to that folder i guess. its in c drive and my files are saved in D:\attachmentfiles....

Comment: @SamSimon I dont think you can do this...you to include image in your website folder or host image on any other server..it can not take local system path..you to provide...Urls..i think...you can create Upload folder insdede your website directory but not outside your website directory

Comment: u know how to host image in other server. actually in my project i have to do the same, have to store all file in some server then to view it. but as initial stage i a trying to save in local system.

Comment: why uou hosting on other server....include your upload folder ni your website...thats best way

Comment: hmm ya..thats the way..

Comment: hope thats solve you issue

Comment: hey 1 more thing i am saving path as uploadedattachment\subfolder\..
how to make it uploadedattachment/subfolder/..?

Comment: since i have dynamically open image or pdf depending on databse value better to store path in / / / format na

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//In Default2.aspx
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>", "Default3.aspx"));
    }

//------------
//In Default3.aspx

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("~\\E:\\karthikeyan\\venky\\pdf\\aaaa.PDF");
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);
        if (buffer != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome code!!! I am using option 2, but how do I open in a new window?

Comment: @Dan B- use this one it have all the settings :) :-
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( 'WebForm2.aspx', null, 'height=700,width=760,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true);

Comment: Thanks @karthi . I figured this out, but I like your script!

Answer (score 0):

It will work with relative path only.
Why in the first place you need path?
Also user Registerstartupscript for script binding to page.

Comment: from gridview i will get path. so i have to use that only . path is full path. wat to do?

Answer (score 0):

In html response you are operating with url paths. So path to open should be valid url (absolute or relative to application), or link to file: "file://path/to/file", which open some directory browser in computer.

You can just put HyperLink control with NavigateUrl with target="_blank" or some javascript. Link to absolute server path will not work.

Comment: so what is the solution for me?? can u suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>", "pdf/aaaa.PDF"));
```

Comment: hey how to use string 'path' there?

Comment: pdf/aaaa.PDF is the path of pdf file you don't put ~/ or / before that pdf/aaaa.PDF

Comment: i think u didnt get my point. i have display image its path is liek below D:\UploadedAttachment\AT\MRD\AT0520130008_15-05-13-03-57-12.pdf
that i am getting from string path.

Comment: i am getting file path from under project solution folder so i am using like that.

Comment: okay..but i want to dislpay file which is out of my proj folder, may be its not possible..anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you bind your FileLocationPath, try to bind it so that your filename

```
D:\UploadedAttachment\AT\MRD\AT0520130008_15-05-13-03-57-12.pdf
```

become

```
file:///D:/UploadedAttachment/AT/MRD/AT0520130008_15-05-13-03-57-12.pdf
```

Comment: alrite, can you take a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

The abort() function is probably your best bet. It's part of the C standard library, and is defined as "causing abnormal program termination" (e.g, a fatal error or crash).